# Validation, where it resides in terms of patterns

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Let's say we have MVC . Our C is smart and only acts as router, we also have Business layer making calls to our Persistence layer - DAOs.

In which part do we put our validation. I am not talking about annotation based validation which is placed on fields of model or DTO classes, but something rather more complex like when you create a validator class itself. How would you illustrate that in formal diagram. I assumed that it resides within a business logic. But at the same time in Spring MVC validation is more oriented on controller.

Please share whatever you think is suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the feeling that validation concerns are also structured in layers, like presentation, business and database.

The names of the layers means nothing to the validation rules in first place. (It means only that these are the layers where the validation rules are checked.)

*You may should notice an important thing, I mainly develop web applications, and this "rules" are for such applications, but not for other things like batch jobs*

lets go from bottom to top:

Database Layer Validation rules.
These are mainly "not null" (for fields and relations). In this layer all the validation constraints exist (and are enforced by the database) that are a must for the implementation itself. It means if there is an validation violation the application crashes. (it does not mean that the Business Logic may calculate something wrong, it really means that the application returns not (useful) result at all). An important thing to understand in Database Layer validation rules, that a rule violation in this layer means a bug. So the aim for these rules is not to check, its aim is to make sure that no critical validation violation can get persisted, and that application doesn't crash every time the database record gets loaded! -- So a violation of this constrains will directly lead to an unresolved exception. Because the cause is a bug, and it is impossible to fix a wrong database record.

Business Layer Validation
This validation Rules exist in the Business Layer, mainly in the service functions. Something like "a username must be unique". A violation of this rules will not crash the program itself, but may result in wrong business results. A second important thing is, that Bussiness Layer Validation rules can be also enforced by the database. But instead of an unresolved exception, the violation exceptions should be cached and handled. And business layer validation violations are not bugs, they are just an wrong input.

Presentation Layer Validation
This validation rules are rules that do not mean anything. Mostly these are some stupid business rules that change every day, and don't influence the business results. These are rules like: "a comment to an stack overflow question must be at least 10 characters long".
I check these rules only in the presentation layer (on server side of course).

Of course a business or database layer constraint should be (as long as it is possible with out too much work) checked in the input forms in the presentation layer too. So for example if there is a field that must be not null, then this should be checked in the input form handler in the presentation layer too.

Comment: `Of course a business or database layer constraint should be (as long as it is possible with out too much work) checked in the input forms in the presentation layer too.` It sounds like validation could be chained in some way. What do you think ?

Comment: @James Poulson: what do you mean by "chained"?

Comment: I think chaining is not what I have had in mind, it is more some kind of repeating: For example a @NotNull Annotation in you command object.

Comment: I see. I just thought of this chaining idea for input validation in the UI. Reproducing the validation logic for each layer could lead to more effort (redundancy ?) when you one could run data through a kind of validation chain/bus. Though I'm not entirely sure how errors/user feedback would be bubbled up.

Comment: I uses JSR303 Bean Validation in order to minimize the redundancy. (I write my custom Validators and Annotations once, and use them in different layers)